# Lucee need duplicate columns in SQL query

Tags: mysql, lucee

Programming in Lucee (Ubuntu, Firefox) and have a query in which I need duplicate columns.  In generic SQL run from my terminal this produces exactly what I ask for.  It works fine in ColdFusion.  But when I run it in Lucee, it refuses to accept the request for the duplicate column.

```
 <cfoutput>
 <cfset mylist = "PersonFn, PersonLn, PersonState, PersonLn">
 <cfquery name = "betty" datasource = "Moxart">
 select #mylist#
 from Person   
 limit 5
 </cfquery>
 </cfoutput>
```

When I get the columnlist for this Query, it has only 3 items in it, having eliminated the duplicate column.  When I run a report against the output:

```
<cfset m = 0>
<cfoutput query = "betty">
<cfloop list = #mylist# index = "xxcol">
<cfset m = m + 1>
#betty[xxcol][currentrow]#
<cfif m EQ 4> 
<br>
</cfif>
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

I get this error:
key [ PersonLn] not found in query, columns are [PersonFn,PersonLn,PersonState]

I really, really need that duplicate column.  Programming around this would be very difficult and excruciating.

I cannot use an alias, because the actual list is chosen by the user and there is no way to know what he might choose, or how many duplicates I might have.  For similar reasons, I cannot reconstruct the data after the query to create the extra columns -- since I don't know what they are.

To be more exact, I probably can do those things, but the amount and complexity of programming is significant -- and all because Lucee just won't do what generic MySql will do.

Can anyone think of a way I can get those duplicate columns back into my output without major programming?

Comment: I think that you can solve your problem just lopping through your list of columns and renaming the duplicated fields, in your case it would have your current list `PersonFn, PersonLn, PersonState, PersonLn` and make it so like `PersonFn, PersonLn, PersonState, PersonLn as PersonLn1`. Although using a string to be concatenated is a very bad practice as your system is prone to sql injections.

Comment: High Jorge,  the problem is that the list is not static.  I don't know which of the columns will be duplicated.  Any other ideas?  I'm aware of injection problems, but have encountered them only on input or update, never on select.

Comment: That's exactly my point. You loop through the original list searching for duplicates and creates the new one like I said and send it to the query. You don't need to know, you need to search.

Comment: Are you aware of any method to find duplicates in a list?  And then hold them so I can assign them an alias?   Or do I get to do it manually?

Comment: There are millions of ways to do it, just pick one. Yes you will have to implement it. See here an example: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-duplicates-in-on-time-and-constant-extra-space/

Comment: You know what I was really looking for is a switch that tells Lucee to proceed with the standard MySql protocol instead of its own individual, out-of-synch approach.  Would you know of such a thing?  There many examples in various languages of being able to do other than the default by use of a switch or parameter.

Comment: I think that Lucee behaves the same as any standard database driver. I think that your problem is not that the columns isn't present in the resultSet (`key [ PersonLn] not found in query`) I think that your problem is that it had renamed the columns like some databases clients do when columns are duplicated in the result set. So try using `<cfdump var=#betty#>` and see what it prints. I think that it will be something like `Personln#1 value..... Personln#2`...

Comment: It was a good idea, but a dump of var = #betty# is missing the duplicate column. I also tried setting a result variable in the query line, but dumping that shows the dup column missing.

Answer (score -1):

You can't have duplicate columns in sql you have to rename it to field1 and field2 for example.

What you seek violates the Sql standard.

Comment: There is no violation of any sql standard in duplicated columns. All RDBMs will deal with it just fine as long as you have only one table like the select shown by the OP. The programming language you use is the one that will have to deal with it and on his case, lucee doesn't. This answer is completely wrong and misleading.

Comment: Good luck getting that to work with a proper Sql server......  Try putting it into a query window for the sql platform and getting it to work.

Comment: It's mysql though.

Comment: What is the mysql query that allows you to select two columns of exactly the same name in a query?

Comment: Mysql: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a334e/1 ; SQLServer: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4a334e/1 ; Postgresql: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4a334/1 ; even Sqllite: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/4a334/1

Comment: What is that?  Sql query is "select x from y"

Comment: You can't use columns of same name if those columns are in different tables like: `table a (colA int); table b(colA int)` then you try: `select a from a, b` this will give a ambiguous column name error.

Comment: When you join them you have to rename one of them or you will get an error.  For two separate queries you can do that.  Try to create a table with two columns of the same name and see how Sql blocks you.

Comment: That is exactly why your answer is wrong. There is no joining on the provided sql wich means that he can use as many duplicated columns as he wants.

Comment: So then the issue becomes how the tool executes your query.  If the tool combines your two queries after returning it from the SQL engine.  Then my point is valid you can't do that in Sql.  But you can do that in your application layer.  My point was about the SQL language.  You can't do that.  If the other tool decides it wants to do the combination of the data with the Sql language it is going to fail because the "SQL" language does not allow that.  You have to either configure your application to not do it on the Sql server or you can't do it.

Comment: Show me a working example in "SQL" not in Lucee or ColdFusion where you can do that and I would agree with you.  Until then I continue to point out you are wrong.

Comment: Well, up here in my comments I put many different links with different engines doing that. You can even try that script yourself on your environment. Sorry, you understand his problem the wrong way. And you are still wrong with your "you can't do that". You can, I showed it with sqlfiddle links. Look the comments above.

Comment: You posted it would give you an error.  That is my point exactly.  I asked for an example that works.  Are you arguing for my point?  It appears you are not understanding.

Comment: Error? Where is the error? All links are working just fine. I can take a printscreen if you like. It is giving you error the SQLFiddle links I provided?

Comment: See it here if you don't believe or are not able to open the sqlfiddle links: http://imgur.com/a/TG2zV

Comment: Just a simple point here.  I ran the query in native MySql from my Terminal.  There was one table with 3 items in it.  I wrote a select with four items, one a duplicate.  It worked perfectly.  So there is no problem with the SQL definitions.  And I had reduced everything I wanted to a single table -- all the joins and their output occur previously in the code.  Cold Fusion does indeed handled this request correctly.  Lucee does not.  If native MySql gives the correct answer, so should Lucee.

Comment: Show me the sql statement please.

Comment: 1 - `create table t (a integer);` 2 - `insert into t values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7);` 3 - `select a, a, a, a, a, a from t;` run it in any RDBMs (that accepts multiple insert, for the insert command).

Comment: That does not have the same field name in the table.  You are selecting the same filed multiple times.  But there is only one source with that name.  That is not the same thing as discussed.  The failure happens when you have two different columns with exactly the same field name.

Comment: Well, we were discussing two different things all the time. The OP's problem is regarding selecting the same column multiple times, Regarding what you are saying, you are totally right and I agree, although it ONLY happens when you have more than one table in the select statement (even if they are the same table). The OP's problem only uses just one table, therefore no problems selecting the same column which is what I was arguing about all the time.

Comment: Maybe a better thing to mention is that most sql engines will not allow you to select the same field name from the same table twice.  Mysql may allow you to do this but it is not in line with the Sql standard.  Mysql also allows you to do other things that are not valid in Sql.  I thought originally he was trying to select two different columns of the same name in the same query.  My thought at this point is.  Maybe Mysql allows you do to this error but the other tool does not.  Thus you can't do it unless you use ColdFusion.

Comment: Basically I am suggesting that Mysql and Cold Fusion do not follow Sql standards but the other tool does.  Thus because these two tools do allow this you should not expect other tools to allow this.  Try doing the same in another Sql database besides Mysql.

Comment: Sorry again man, you are wrong when you say `is that most sql engines will not allow you to select the same field name from the same table twice` it is completely the other way around. And it is stated in the SQL Ansi also. I even provided you an imgur link since my original sqlfiddle wont work here it is again with all major database engines. http://imgur.com/a/TG2zV

Comment: It also work for Oracle and DB2, unfortunately sqlfiddle doesn't work for oracle and doesn't have DB2.